# Use sAMAccountName instead of userPrincipalName in LDAP auth in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ldap

So I am using the code below to connect to our LDAP server in my spring boot app, I can authorized successfully using the userPrincipalName -> (**LastName.FirstName@enterprise.com**), but I want to use the assigned sAMAccountName instead (**ID00001**).

I messed around with the setSearchFilter by doing: provider.setSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName ={0})")

but it's not working. (I'm getting bad credentials)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/myapplication")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("", "ldap://test.enterprise.com","dc=ORG1, dc=ORG2");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})"); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        provider.setSearchFilter("(userPrincipalName={0})"); // THIS WORKS
        return provider;
    }
}
```

EDIT: OK turns out I have been using the wrong field, there is another field: sAMAccountName that has the same value that I should be using, updated the title and question contents.

EDIT:

Ok I tried:

```
provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(cn={0}))");
provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))");
provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(cn={1}))");
provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))");
```

and it's still the same error,

bad credentials, AcceptSecurityContextError, 52e v2580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue but instead of using spring ldap dependencies, I created a custom authentication provider that implements AuthenticationProvider and and used the following code to connect to ldap and validate the credentials:

autowire it to WebSecurityConfig class.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
   
   
   @Autowired
   private UserDetails userDetails;
   
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws 
    AuthenticationException {
        String user = authentication.getName();
        String pass = authentication.getCredentials.ToString();

        try {
            if (isRegistrered(user,pass) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,pass, new 
                ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    private isRegisterd(String user, String pass) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap_server:389");
            // 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "DOMAIN\\USER"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "PASSWORD");

            // Create the initial context

            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            if(ctx != null) {
                ctx.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {           
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    
    private void retrieveUserDetails(DirContext ctx, String username) throws NamingException {
        String userSearchBase = "dc=TEST,dc=SAMPLE";
        String userSearchFilter = String.format("sAMAccountName=%s", username);
        
        //any attributes that you want
        String[] attributes = { "sAMAccountName", "department" };
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        controls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);
        SearchResult result = null;
        NamingEnumeration<?> users = ctx.search(userSearchBase, userSearchFilter, controls);
        
        while(users.hasmore()) {
            result = (SearchResult) users.next();
            Attributes attr = result.getAttribtutes();
            String sAMAccountName = attr.get("sAMAccountName").get(0).toString();
            String department = attr.get("department").get(0).toString();
            
            //assign to autowired object to be accessed anywhere
            this.userDetails.setAccountName(sAMAccountName);
            this.userDetails.setDepartment(department);     
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach by using LdapAuthenticationProvider. I use LdapAuthenticationProvider with a single parameter constructor.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Profile("integration")
public class SecurityConfigurationT extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
 
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
 
    public SecurityConfigurationT(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder,
            TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }
 
    @PostConstruct
    public void initIntegration() {
 
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                    .authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
 
    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator());
    }
 
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() throws Exception {
        PasswordPolicyAwareContextSource contextSource = new PasswordPolicyAwareContextSource("ldaps://int.root.company.ag:636");
        contextSource.setUserDn("CN=system_user,OU=companygroup svc accs,DC=int,DC=root,DC=company,DC=ag");
        contextSource.setPassword("XXXXXX");
        return contextSource;
    }
 
    // Use this for other filter such as "sAMAccountName". 
    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator() {
        BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(ldapContextSource());
        authenticator.setUserSearch(new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("OU=company,OU=companygroup users,DC=int,DC=root,DC=company,DC=ag", "(sAMAccountName={0})", ldapContextSource()));
        return authenticator;
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.stevenschwenke.de/LDAPWithSpringSecurity